# Вместо переключения окон пишет *ИМЯ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ* has stopped

Tags: java, android, activity

Вот 1 activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText nforma;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playbut);
         nforma = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nickf);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent intent;
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.playbut:
                    intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra ("", nforma.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);


break;
            }
        }


}
```

Вот 2 активити:

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
  TextView nick;
  TextView mont;
  TextView subt;
  TextView nastt;
  TextView rt;
  int mon=100;
  int nast=10;
  int r=0;
  int sub=0;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    nick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nickt);
    subt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subt);
    nastt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nastt);
    mont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mont);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nick1 = intent.getStringExtra("");
    nick.setText(nick1);


    Button PIAR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butpiar);
    Button zbNAch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butzbnach);
    Button stream = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butstream);

    PIAR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
                 mon=mon-50;
                        sub=sub+25;
                    }
                            });
    mont.setText("Деньги "+mon);
    nastt.setText("Настроение "+nast);
    rt.setText("Рейтинг "+r);
    subt.setText("Подписчики "+sub);
  }
}
```

вот логи

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: ru.bget.j90297rm.ssop3, PID: 4710
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.bget.j90297rm.ssop3/ru.bget.j90297rm.ssop3.GameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at ru.bget.j90297rm.ssop3.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:49)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Вторая активити в манифесте прописана?

Answer (score 1):

В putExtra передай нормальный, не пустой ключ`intent.putExtra ("somekey", nforma.getText().toString());`
А в другом принимай его

Comment: А если мне надо чтобы форма была пустая?

Comment: а еще это не помогает. не открывается 2 форма

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле косяк был в том что я `setText` не в том месте поставил